Al usar el login de asp por defecto el sweetalert no me funciona con los authorize pero sin ellos si, que puede ser?
 <script>
        const formulario = document.querySelector('form');

        formulario.onsubmit = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            // Validaciones
            const nombreInput = document.getElementById('Nombre');
            const propositoInput = document.getElementById('Proposito');
            const coordinadorInput = document.getElementById('Coordinador');
            const lugarInput = document.getElementById('Lugar');
            const fechaInput = document.getElementById('Fecha');

            const estadoInput = document.getElementById('Estado');

            if (nombreInput.value.trim() === '' || nombreInput.value.length > 50) {
                if (nombreInput.value.length > 50) {
                    swal.fire("El nombre debe contener menos caracteres", "", "error");
                } else {
                    swal.fire("Debe completar el nombre", "", "error");
                }
                return;
            }

            if (propositoInput.value.trim() === '' || propositoInput.value.length > 500) {
                if (propositoInput.value.length > 500) {
                    swal.fire("El propósito debe contener menos caracteres", "", "error");
                } else {
                    swal.fire("Debe completar el propósito", "", "error");
                }
                return;
            }

            if (coordinadorInput.value.trim() === '' || coordinadorInput.value.length > 50) {
                if (coordinadorInput.value.length > 50) {
                    swal.fire("El coordinador debe contener menos caracteres", "", "error");
                } else {
                    swal.fire("Debe completar el coordinador", "", "error");
                }
                return;
            }

            if (lugarInput.value.trim() === '' || lugarInput.value.length > 100) {
                if (lugarInput.value.length > 100) {
                    swal.fire("El lugar debe contener menos caracteres", "", "error");
                } else {
                    swal.fire("Debe completar el lugar", "", "error");
                }
                return;
            }

            // Suponiendo que `fechaInput` es un elemento de entrada de tipo fecha
            if (fechaInput.value.trim() === '') {
                swal.fire("Debe completar la fecha", "", "error");
                return;
            }

            // Validar que la fecha sea posterior a la actual
            const fechaIngresada = new Date(fechaInput.value);
            const fechaActual = new Date();

            if (fechaIngresada <= fechaActual) {
                swal.fire("La fecha debe ser posterior a la fecha actual", "", "error");
                return;
            }


            if (estadoInput.value === '') {
                swal.fire("Debe seleccionar un estado", "", "error");
                return;
            }

            // Envío del formulario
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', formulario.action, true);
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    swal.fire("Reunión guardada exitosamente!", "", "success");
                    formulario.reset();
                }
            };
            xhr.send(new FormData(formulario));
        };
    </script>

Esa es mi validacion y este mi authorize
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Ejecutivo")]


Te retorna algun error por consola ??

me ha dado error CORS

Por favor, siempre agrega eso a la publicación.
